# BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method specialization does not exist

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am getting this small issue. Below is the source code

**Doctor Model:**

```
class Doctor extends Model {
......
....
     public function specialization() {
        return $this->HasMany('App\Specialization');
    }
}
```

**Specialization Model:**

```
class Specialization extends Model {
......
....
     public function doctor () {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Doctor', 'id');
     }
}
```

**Specialization Model:**
Here the spec_id is a foreign key

```
class DoctorController extends Controller
{
......
....
 //Create a Doctor
    public function createDoctor(Request $request) {
    $doctor = new Doctor();
    $doctor->doctor_id = $request->input('doctor_id');
    // $doctor->spec_id = $request->input('spec_id');
    $doctor->spec_id = $request->specialization()->id;
    $doctor->dob = $request->input('dob');
    $doctor->age = $request->input('age');
    $doctor->gender = $request->input('gender');
    $doctor->qualification = $request->input('qualification');
    $doctor->experience = $request->input('experience');
    $doctor->phone_number = $request->input('phone_number');
    // $doctor->email = $request->user()->email;
    $doctor->email = $request->input('email');
    // $doctor->user_id = $request->user()->user_id;
    $doctor->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $doctor->save();
    return response()->json(['doctor' => $doctor], 201);
    }
}
```

Please let me know how do I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is most probably from `... = $request->specialization()->id;` where the specialization() method doesn't exist. The error message also mentions Macroable, which makes me believe that you are type-hinting the Request facade in the method signature, not the correct `Illuminate\Http\Request` type.

Check your use-statements at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the request does not have specialization, you to try to use Log, to find out what the request has

Answer (score 0):

`Request $request` is not an eloquent model.

Try using **$doctor instead of $request**
`$doctor->specialization->id` and am sure you'll be able to get the id.

Also, the HasMany is spelled wrongly. Change the **'H' -> 'h'**